# Why this c program output like this?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
main
{
    int x[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int i,*j;
    j=x;
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        printf("%u",j);
        j++;
    }
}
```

output:

```
65512
65514
65516
65518
65520
```

But when I change the `printf` to"

```
printf("%u",&j[i]);
```

Output is:

```
65512
65516
65520
65524
65528
```

Why the address differ by 2 in first case and 4 in second casee?

What is wrong with just printing `j` and printing `&j[i]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, just to make it clear, you are printing the pointer `j`, and not the pointed value, `*j`

Now, regarding the printed address. In your second example:

```
for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
  printf("%u",&j[i]); 
  j++;
```

`&j[i]` equals to `(j+i)`. `i` is incremented in each iteration, which contributes 2 to the pointer's value, and `j` is incremented too, which contributes another 2.

Comment: @lgor Oks "j" is also an address and "&j[i]" is also an address only know.. i am printing those two.. why the address differs????

Comment: I think he was pretty clear about why the addresses differ.  You are incrementing both `j` and `i`, so obviously `j` (your first example) will increase slower than `j+i` (your second example).  To get the same output as your first example, you'd want `&j[0]`.

Answer (score 3):

You get jumps of 4 in the second example because you are incrementing `j` *and* offsetting by `i`!  Both of these contribute a difference of 2.

Note also that `printf` is not type-safe; it is up to you to ensure that the arguments match the format-specifiers.  You have specified `%u`, but you've given it an `int *`, you should use `%p` for pointers.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth sorry "j=x" i forgot this line in code.. now i updated the code check it.........

Comment: Note: some compilers can warn you about passing wrong arguments to printf, but you have to enable warnings